# Should I expose the properties of my classes?

Tags: c#, java, c++, oop

During all my studies I learned that when ever I want to give a user access to an inner property, I shouldn't give a direct access to the property, but give access through get/set method, for example:

```
class myClass
{
    private int x;

    public void SetX (int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int GetX ()
    {
        return this.x
    }
}
```

As it gives the added benefits of allowing the programmer to change the engine completely more easily without affecting the user, easier de-bugging and gives more options for checking validity of input.

However, since I started learning and writing in C# I noticed that most of the classes that are "native" to the language expose their properties, for example, to set/get the location or sizes of a rectangle ([`System.Drawing.Rectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.aspx)), you can simply access directly the `X`, `Y`, `Width` and `Height` properties.

- The only benefits I see of exposing the properties is that the code is a little simpler. Are there any other benefits to exposing properties?
- When should I expose the properties, and when shouldn't I?

Comment: [Read this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/properties-vs-public-variables.html). read the comments also

Comment: @ManishMishra I was going to write some answer, but then i read your comment, thanks for the link

Comment: @ManishMishra, your link is great, Post it as an answer (with a summation of what is written there) and I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, your question is Properties vs Public Variables. When to use what?

Read [this Post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/properties-vs-public-variables.html), including the comments.

A quick summary of entire discussion:

- Reflection works differently on variables vs. properties, so if you rely on reflection,
  it's easier to use all properties.
- You can't databind against a variable.
- Changing a variable to a property is a breaking change.

Trivial property implementation of exposing a data member is a lot of code for no or little gain and only rational reasons can be:

- To provide read-only access to a member var that cannot be declared const for some reason
- If you're writing a component that is meant for use by some 3rd parties and there exists any chance that the component will have to be replaced without requiring a rebuild by those users (changing a public member variable to a property breaks the interface, so a rebuild is needed).

Also, wrap public fields in properties, for two reasons - one is that you can't change it later without breaking binary compatibility. Two is that you can't bind to fields.

```
Reflection code against fields looks very different from reflection code against 
properties (FieldInfo vs. PropertyInfo for starters). So even if you can 
recompile against the new binary, if you use reflection on that field 
you're hosed.
```

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing Properties and Fields. In C#, Properties can be used like public fields, but internally their get/set methods are called. As an example, your class with a property would look like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    // Field, direct access to the internal representation
    private int x; 

    // Property, access via methods, but syntax like field access
    public int X {
        get { return this.x; } // generates a get-method "int get_X()"
        set { this.x = value; } // generates a set-method "void set_X(int value)"
    }
}
```

When you now set the property X like this: **`myClass.X = 42`** , the compiler translates this to **`myClass.set_X(42)`**, which calls the method declared in the **`set`** block. The Field-like syntax is just for convenience.

So it is true that you should prefer to expose set/get-methods. It's just that in C#, the preferred way of doing so is via Properties, which abstract away the actual calling of these methods and allow you to use them like fields.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you use properties instead of getter/setter methods, since they provide the same functionality. Note that fields != properties. See [MSDN: Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, the advantage of not giving direct access to your variables is that you can change the implementation without any changes for the user of your class. And in terms of object oriented programming, I think that's an important thing.

Also, with using properties, you can still influence the working of "get" or "set". Which can be useful in certain situations.